# ParseQueryAdapter versus RecyclerView.adapter

Tags: android, parse-platform, android-recyclerview, android-parsequeryadapter

I have a card view layout. I created it using RecyclerView.Adapter and CardView layout. I am using Parse for my backend. Data in cards get populated from query to Parse. What are the pros and cons of using ParseQueryAdapter instead of going for RecyclerView.Adapter except from pagination. Is there anything I would be missing if I go for RecyclerView.Adapter.